# Could the Traveler become a Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

The Q are almost all-powerful (but not all-knowing).  There seem to be other species which are sort of sub-Q, such as Guinan, who is very knowledgeable, but not all-knowing (consider 'Time's Arrow' where she didn't know if she should tell Picard about the past or not).  What about the Traveler, though?  According to Memory Alpha, the Traveler:

> had the ability to alter space, time and warp fields with the power of
>   his mind. He could phase out of time and dimension and move between
>   planets and starships.

This is pretty close to being all-powerful, so is it possible that The Traveler could become all-powerful i.e. a Q (by 'become' I mean could it evolve into a similar species with the same abilities as the Q without the intervention of the Q?)

Comment: "Hide and Q" seemed to demonstrate that any sapient being could become a Q, and if something's not sapient, the Q could probably make it be.  Really, questions of "can" and "can't" regarding the Q are all pretty much foregone conclusions.

Comment: @jwodder - good point made.  I've altered the question accordingly

Comment: The Q aren't all-knowing, almost all the episode plots involving Q play out the way they do because he doesn't know about something.  And Quinn makes it a point to tell the Voyager crew that they're not all-powerful, despite what it may look like to less-advanced species.

Comment: Guinan's only unusual ability was a vague sense that reality was "correct", plus knowledge/wisdom she's simply accumulated in 500+ years of being alive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are beings who are more powerful than or similar in power to the Q, such as the [Douwd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd) and [Nacene](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nacene). Novels establish [other beings such as (*)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/0#0) that exceed them in power as well. It seems likely that the Traveller, or his species, could certainly evolve to be similar in power to a Q. Q does, after all, believe that humans have the potential to evolve beyond his own species, which seems to have hit an evolutionary dead-end. Why not the [Traveller](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Traveller)? Even the female Q seems impressed by him.

Of course, the real difference between the Q and many other non-corporeal beings seems to be their existence in a separate continuum of their own. The Traveller may not evolve along those lines, meaning that any answer can only be speculative.

Comment: The Nacene didn't seem to me to be anywhere near Q and Douwd abilities...

Comment: I don't recall the Q, even in novels, ever travelling outside of the Milky Way. The Nacene can. It made sense to include them in an answer about the Traveller.

Comment: The Enterprise also crossed the Galactic Barrer without outside help.  Is the Federation currently at/near Q Continuum abilities?

Comment: Don't be an ass. The *Enterprise* didn't travel to another galaxy or across whole quadrants in the blink of an eye. The Traveller and the Nacene can. The Douwd probably can. The Organians probably can. While the Q seem to travel the Milky Way at will they have never been shown to travel intergalactically, even in novels.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - The Q demonstrate the ability to travel anywhere in the universe (and outside the universe) in Voyager "Death Wish"

Comment: @Richard: Not unless I am seriously misremembering that episode they don't. Any quotation or other source?

Comment: @Jamessheridan - Quinn takes the voyager to the big bang (from the outside)

Comment: I tried responding to this an hour ago, but my connection died. That's more time travel than space travel, but fair enough. I never said the Q couldn't travel outside the galaxy, merely that they didn't.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - You can't get much more outside the galaxy than that. In the books, the Q travel extensively outside the galaxy and were even responsible for creating "the great barrier" all the way around the galaxy to prevent intergalactic invasion.

Comment: That barrier was erected to keep out 0, not an extra-galactic invasion. It doesn't stop the Kelvans or the creatures from *Catspaw*, after all. Nor the Douwd, the Traveller, or the Nacene, for that matter. And I don't claim to have read every *Star Trek* novel, but I don't recall them travelling outside the galaxy - excluding time travel and inter-dimensional travel - even on those novels.

Comment: @JamesSheridan lol naw the Q are mentioned observing many other galaxies ours is just the most interesting. Elder male Q talks about this to younger male Q when they discuss his imminent death at the hands of the Omega continuum concerning the destruction of all life in the alpha and gamma quad by the borg. All the time they talk about going everywhere in the universe and doing everything possible and how they get bored.

Comment: moreover female q mother of younger q describes all Q as all powerful but not omnipotent.

Comment: the most recent books from the voyager series describe the Q Continuum as that which recreates the multiverse every time is explodes or implodes.

Comment: @JamesSheridan The Q and Douwd are reality warpers.  They bend the universe to their will.  The [Zalkonians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transfigurations_(episode)) are just starting to evolve to that point.  Organians may or may not be there, and Kelvans explicitly use (super-advanced) technology.  The Nacene are not, theirs is more on-par with the Federation.  That is why I don't think they count.  Being able to travel through the Galactic Barrier and across great distances isn't a good qualifier, as the Borg can also do that.

Comment: @Izkata: The Nacene are far more advanced than the Federation. I have no idea how you could ever think they were not, given their extra-galactic nature and the sheer power of their subspace drive system. I also fail to see how a being of "illusions and false surroundings" is necessarily a "reality warper." Even the Q seem to have trouble 'warping' reality' from time-to-time. I'm also unsure as to why technology is necessarily separate from biological evolution; V'Ger comes to mind as a being that was undoubtedly super-powerful, yet a machine, and its merger with Decker increased its abilities.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I never said they were not more advanced than the Federation, I said that they were not similar in power to the Q Continuum, who are the most powerful known beings in Star Trek canon.  I just tried to qualify it with an example as to why your using "ability to travel outside the Milky Way" was flawed, which was apparently the wrong example to use.

Comment: @Izkata: And I never said the Q couldn't travel outside the Milky Way, merely that they didn't, which is obviously wrong in light of the information in the novels. In hindsight, there are definitely species better than the Nacene I could have used there, but they were in my head for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

No the most recent books (Eternal Tides, Protectors) from the Voyager series describe the Q Continuum as opposing the Omega Continuum responsible for remaking and interacting with the **multi**verse when the Omega continuum destroys it. The sentient beings known as Q have access to all that power but only exists since the last reformation of the Universe because of the actions of a race (beyond the powers of the Caeliar) that fractured the Omega Continuum and joined it (and the Q Continuum) to our own.
The Travelers are no where remotely near that powerful. They have trouble displacing groups of people across the galaxy.

Comment: Please indicate *which* "most recent" books you are referencing.

Comment: @Xantec done as req

Comment: Thanks. This way even in the future people will know which books are the most recent.

Comment: I really wish the *Star Trek* books would organise some sort of canon, as the *Star Wars* books have done. This new series sounds as if it directly contradicts an earlier series that established a race known as "Them" in the position the Omega Continuum seems to occupy here. And this is hardly the first occasion of the *Star Trek EU* contradicting itself. It makes answering questions that rely on information from the *ST EU* very difficult, as was seen recently in the several Borg questions where Richard and I both offered different answers that were equally correct.