# Has there ever been any suggestion of any interaction or connection between the Q & the Traveler in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

In some ways the Traveler appears to possess almost Q like (or at least proto-Q like) powers, so has there ever been any interaction or suggested connection or relationship between the two in the existing Star Trek canon that might shed a little light on that?

One way to rephrase the question (or consider it from a different angle) could perhaps be to ask:

> Are the Traveler's perhaps an early offshoot of the Q (from before they became the Q) or might they be considered an example of parallel evolution heading in the same direction as the Q but currently at an earlier stage.

That would perhaps fall too far within the realms of "primarily opinion based" however so I leave my question as originally formulated.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Could the Traveller become a Q?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53185/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor : that question asks if the traveler could become a Q which I think is adequately answered by the fact that "anything can become a Q if the Q will it", this question is more along the lines of "are the Travelers in some way related to the Q" which isn't the same question at all :)

Comment: There are many powerful species in the canon. Should we say that Nagilum, Organians, and Douwds are also related to Q? The Traveler has some neat abilities, but they pale in comparison to Q’s.

Comment: @HamSandwich : not including Trelane in that list?

Comment: @HamSandwich : I know they pale which is why I said proto-Q like.

Comment: @HamSandwich : the Douwds powers are close in some ways yes but obviously not up to full Q scratch or he could have reversed what he did & restore his home's planet & it's people, his powers don't really seem to work on the same principles as the Q's though while (to me) the traveler's (if far less) do.

Comment: @Pelinore - Trelane was retconned into a Q in one of the tie in novels

Comment: @Radhil : fair-do, it would certainly makes sense, is that considered hard-canon then?

Comment: @Pelinore - probably not, but I'm fuzzier on canon matters, compared to other users here

Comment: Pelinore, this is Small-Universe Thinking, and it’s generally frowned upon. The Traveler almost died in the first episode in which he appears. There’s no reason to think he’s a prototype Q.

Comment: @HamSandwich : Sure but though that's certainly the thought behind my question it's not the question I did ask, if I had asked that question it would have been "primarily opinion based" which is why I asked for any known in universe interactions or connections between the two instead, and the answer to that still interests me.

Comment: The only known connection is in the non-canon Q Continuum novel, where the female Q appears impressed that Wesley had an association with The Traveler. Outside of that, presumably Q has knowledge of the other, since Q apparently knows basically everything of import (and a species as advanced as The Traveler would certainly not be considered unimportant).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apocrypha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Traveler#Apocrypha) (i.e. non-canon) section of the Memory Alpha entry on The Traveler:

> According to the [*Q Continuum*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_Q_Continuum_(novel_series)) series, The Traveler even has a significant reputation among the [Q Continuum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_Continuum); when the [female Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_(female)) learned that Wesley had been chosen by The Traveler, she was almost impressed by this fact.